# Creating multiple objects using the same instance

Tags: java, oop, object

I just saw this tutorial creating multiple objects using the same instance by applying the DAO pattern and tried it in a simple console, but I always get this message `java.lang.NullPointerException` I'm now confused, as far as I know, a constructor can be used once only, and the object will be immutable. Kindly look at this:

**Fighter.java**

```
public class Fighter {
    private String style;

    public Fighter() {}

    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }
    public void setStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }
}
```

**FightersDAO.java**

```
public class FightersDAO {
    public List<Fighter> getFighters(){

        List <Fighter> fighter = new ArrayList<>();
        String [] styles= { "Karate", "Sumo", "Pro-Wrestling" };

        for(int i=0; i < styles.length; i++) {
            Fighter temp = new Fighter();;
            temp.setStyle(styles[i]);
            fighter.add(temp);
        }
        return fighter;
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
public class Demo {
    private static FightersDAO fighterDAO;
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        List <Fighter> fighters = fighterDAO.getFighters();

        for(Fighter e: fighters) {
            System.out.println(e.getStyle()); //this should output the objects, but nothing shows
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it null? What part did went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `fighterDAO` is never initialized. Therefore you get a NPE here:

```
List <Fighter> fighters = fighterDAO.getFighters();
```

To fix that use:

```
private static FightersDAO fighterDAO = new FightersDAO();
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

`private static FightersDAO fighterDAO;`
I think there is a problem because it is not initialized.

Change it:
`private static FightersDAO fighterDAO = new FightersDAO();`

Answer (score 0):

In your code
private static FightersDAO fighterDAO;//  here is not initialized. its just a declaration so fighterDAO = null;

while executing below code will throw exeption
 List  fighters = fighterDAO.getFighters();// means null.getFighters();

Below is the correct code

package aks;

import java.util.List;

public class Demo {
    private static FightersDAO fighterDAO= new FightersDAO();

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    List <Fighter> fighters = fighterDAO.getFighters();

    for(Fighter e: fighters) {
        System.out.println(e.getStyle()); 
    }
}
```

}

You can analyse this by just debuggin on eclise or any IDE

If you want same instance use below code

private static FightersDAO fighterDAO = new FightersDAO();